# Flex cannot create lex.yy.c

Tags: c, flex-lexer

I am new to flex so I apologize if it's a stupid question. 
 I have a "Hello world" program :

```
%{
#undef yywrap
#define yywrap() 1

%}

%%

[\n] {
printf("Hello World\n");    
}


 %%

main()
{
  yylex(); //calling the rules section
}
```

When i run flex  hello.l in cmd the next error occurs.

```
C:\Users\Robbi\Desktop\flex_program>flex hello.l
flex: could not create lex.yy.c
```

I have installed flex in C folder and copy the path to 'Environment Variable'

Comment: Please check if `flex` has writing rights in that directory, otherwise set them. There is a whitespace before the second `%%` in your listing. It results in a couple of `testflex.l:16: unrecognized rule` and `testflex.l:18: unrecognized rule` with my version `2.5.35` but one never knows.

Comment: Better still, run it in a directory that you *do* have write access to. You'll have the same problem when running *yacc* or *bison*, the compiler, the linker, and ultimately the generated program itself.

Answer (score -2):

I know its pretty late but had the same error and it worked with sudo lex filename.lex.

Comment: Wrong solution. You should run it in a folder of your own that you have write access to.